# Why is only a part of the TailwindCSS classes rendering in my React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following code in my React app which I copied from the TailwindCSS documentation

```
<div className="row border-solid border-4 border-light-blue-500">
```

However, when my React app is rendering, only the 'border-width: 4px!important;' portion gets rendered and the border-solid and border-light-blue-500 portions don't get rendered. Why is this?

Comment: my mistake, the 'border-4' css line was being rendered by Bootstrap. I haven't actually installed TailwindCSS properly at all.